# FCM, send multiple devices without tokens?

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send FCM to everyone who installed the app. Is it essential to get everyone's tokens from the database every time?

My app is using firebase firestore overall. If there are 100,000 users,

do I have to read 100,000 from database to send fcm each time? (I think it`s little heavy stuff isn`t it?)

another workroad exists?

I wonder Is the only way to send it by putting it in the registration ID?

And can you send it on time? All apps on the market send push messages on time, but if you read 100,000 and send fcm separately, shouldn't it arrive like this at 9:01 or 9:02? But why do I always get messages at 9 o'clock?

What are the methods, logic, algorithms they use (the way companies usually use)

I still have no clue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "send to all users" operation in FCM. You either will have to send to each token (that's not a heave operation for FCM, which handles billions of such calls every second), or you have to subscribe all instances to a specific topic and then send to that topics (which ends up the same behind the scenes, just with Firebase loading the tokens for the topic for you).

This has been covered a few times before, so I recommend checking:

- [How do you send a Firebase Notification to all devices via CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237559/how-do-you-send-a-firebase-notification-to-all-devices-via-curl)
- [How to send notifications to all devices using Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427525/how-to-send-notifications-to-all-devices-using-firebase-cloud-messaging/38427849#38427849)
- [Firebase Cloud Messaging - Send message to all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772167/firebase-cloud-messaging-send-message-to-all-users)

---

The notifications panel in the Firebase console has an option to deliver messages at a specific time, but no such option exists in the Firebase Cloud Messaging API. You'll have to either implement your own mechanism to schedule the delivery, or you can deliver a *data* message right away and then only display the notification on the device when it's time.

This also has been covered a few times before, so check:

- [Firebase Messaging FCM Distribution over configurable time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67125983/firebase-messaging-fcm-distribution-over-configurable-time-interval)
- [How can scheduled Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications be made outside of the Firebase Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713668/how-can-scheduled-firebase-cloud-messaging-notifications-be-made-outside-of-the)
- [Flutter Firebase Messaging: How to send push notifications to users at specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733889/flutter-firebase-messaging-how-to-send-push-notifications-to-users-at-specified)